# Regex between \begin{enumerate} and \end{enumerate}

Tags: c#, regex

So, I have a string like

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item My first item 
\item My second item
\end{enumerate}
```

And need with a Regex get the part between `\begin{enumerate}` and the `\end{enumerate}`. I've tried to have the pattern `\\begin{enumerate}(.*?)\\end{enumerate}` and in online checkers it works but not when I run my code.

Anyone in a mind of helping me out I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?s)\\begin{enumerate}(.*?)\\end{enumerate}
```

C#:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"(?s)\\begin{enumerate}(.*?)\\end{enumerate}");
```

`(?s)` in the beginning of the pattern forces a dot to match newline symbols, and to match a backslash, you need to double it in a verbatim string literal, or quadruple it in a normal regular string literal.

Perhaps, you'd like to enforce case insensitive matching, too. Then, replace `(?s)` with `(?si)`.

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you so very much. I just can't get my head around Regex...

Comment: Glad to help, but do not give up on regexes, please find some time and read at least some of this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/. I think that site explains a lot of regex mysteries in a comprehensive and clear way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` or use `modifier s`, since `.` does not contain `\n`

```
var re = new Regex(@"\\begin{enumerate}([\s\S]*?)\\end{enumerate}");
```

Comment: If you are in two minds about why your answer is not the accepted one: 1) `\b` is `First or last character in a word`, 2) `\e` is `Escape`.

Comment: thanks.. i was concentrating more on `[\s\S]` :P .. I will keep it in mind while answering further.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an escaping problem here, use verbatim strings. Also, the braces should be escaped. And finally, did you use `RegexOptions.Singleline` so that the `.` metacharacter is allowed to match newlines?

```
var re = new Regex(@"\\begin\{enumerate\}(.*?)\\end\{enumerate\}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Note the `@` just before the `"`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as thought you may only want to use the text in between these tags so if thats the case you could use a positive lookbehind and lookahead and that would get you:

\n\item My first item \n\item My second item\end

so try this instead. I have added some escape characters for you so it will work.

(?<=\begin{enumerate}).*?(?=\end{enumerate})

I would probably use the @ symbol instead of the escape characters as with the second answer. I think it looks easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this with plain old Linq. E.g.:

```
var s = "\\begin{enumerate}\n" +
        "\\item My first item\n" +
        "\\item My second item\n" +
        "\\end{enumerate}";

var allRows = s.Split('\n').ToList();

var items = allRows
        .Skip(1)
        .Take(allRows.Count - 2)
        .Select(i => i.Replace(@"\item ", String.Empty));
```